# How to show view in backbone.js (alert is not display in router.js)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I am trying to learn backbone .I am trying to load my first view after learing few tutorials .Could you please tell me why my router function not call .Actually I am trying to show My first view .I add alert in my router function but it not display alert. I am not able to show my view here is my code .
http://goo.gl/jgFWmZ

```
var routers = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/": "showFirstPage"
    },
    showFirstPage:function(){
     alert('--')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new instance of router object and start backbone history. you may add a simple code such this :

```
var route = new routers();
Backbone.history.start();
```

please review this bin http://jsbin.com/fasozifawe/1/edit

Comment: could you please give your code link ..please share code ..what I did wrong

Comment: @please remove this answer not worning

Comment: your code has some mistakes. i am using mobile now and cant create a fiddle for you. but check this mistake. 

1.update your link to newest version of backbone and underscore. for example back has hard dependency to underscore >1.5 , you have used 1.1. 
2. use empty string to route root. ( you have used "/"). you should use "".
3. as I said create new instance of route and start history.
if it does not work i will create a fiddle for you soon

Comment: your code show alert but where is my view..could I use marionette .js file

Comment: Sir please load a first view using marionette .js file